# Нахождение повторяющихся элементов в массиве

Tags: c#, массивы, алгоритм

На собеседовании задали такой вопрос: "Дан массив размером n-элементов. Как за один проход найти повторяющиеся элементы массива? (ограничения по памяти нету)"

Comment: И в чем проблема? В массиве что лежит? Числа?

Comment: Если ограничений на использование других коллекций нет, то проще всего сделать так: `var set = new HashSet<T>(); foreach (var item in array) if (!set.Add(item)) Console.WriteLine(item);`

Comment: Подсказка намекает на то, что можно выделить массив нулевых элементов размером, равным числу возможных значений элементов исходного массива. Встретив элемент со значением x, увеличивать x-овый элемент этого массива. Если достигается значение 2 - значит, дубликат...

Comment: @АндрейNOP, не совсем понимаю как можно сделать такой обход. Натолките на мысль

Comment: Выполняем сортировку подсчётом (любым доступным методом - накоплением значений или в статический массив), в процессе выводим элементы, промежуточное количество которых равно 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

есть как минимум 1 вариант с одним проходом:

```
// хешсет, скорость - линейная, память - линейная
public void PrintDublicates_HashSet(int[] n)
{
    var set = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach(var item in n) 
        if (!set.Add(item)) 
            Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Варианты с несколькими проходами

```
// сортировка - скорость - nlogn, память - константа
public void PrintDublicates_Sort(int[] n)
{
    Array.Sort(n);
    for(int i=1; i<n.Length; i++)
        if (n[i] == n[i-1]) Console.WriteLine(n[i]);
}

// подсчет. Скорость - линейная, память - зависит от значения макс элемента
// при условии, что элементы неотрицательны
public void PrintDublicates_Count(int[] n)
{
    int max = n.Max();
    int[] counts = new int[max+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n.Length; i++)
    {
        counts[n[i]]++;
        if (counts[n[i]] > 1) Console.WriteLine(n[i]);
    }
}
```

Проверка

```
PrintDublicates_HashSet(new int[] {1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7});
Console.WriteLine();
PrintDublicates_Sort(new int[] {1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7});
Console.WriteLine();
PrintDublicates_Count(new int[] {1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7});
```

Вывод в консоль

```
1
3

1
3

1
3
```

Comment: Меня смущает, что второй вариант помимо обхода содержит сортировку (по сути - тот же обход, просто неявный), что входит в противоречие с условиями задачи. Но в целом - UV.

Comment: Ну и `n.Max()` — так-то тоже еще один проход. Да и вообще, вдруг там какие-то отрицательные числа еще встречаются

Comment: @AK ха, я оять недочитал задачу. Сейчас поправлю ответ

Comment: @АндрейNOP про неотрицательные тож добавил